# Serializing RAW SQL query Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, orm

Hope you doing well. I need to serialize my RAW SQL query:

```
SELECT nn.*,nm.*FROM notifications_newsletter nn LEFT JOIN notifications_message nm ON nn.id=nm.newsletter_id_id ORDER by nm.status DESC
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models


class Newsletter(models.Model):
    start_datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    text = models.TextField(blank=True)
    filter = models.ForeignKey('Filter', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    end_datetime = models.DateTimeField()


class Message(models.Model):
    send_datetime = models.DateTimeField('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', auto_now=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    newsletter_id = models.ForeignKey('Newsletter', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    client_id = models.ForeignKey('Client', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.core.serializers import serialize
from django.http import HttpResponse

from .models import Newsletter


def some_view(request):
    sql = 'SELECT nn.*,nm.*FROM notifications_newsletter nn ' \
          'LEFT JOIN notifications_message nm ' \
          'ON nn.id=nm.newsletter_id_id ORDER by nm.status DESC'
    qs = Newsletter.objects.raw(sql)
    qs_json = serialize('json', qs)
    return HttpResponse(qs_json, content_type='application/json')
```

If I do it with `serializers.serialize()` **all joined data (message table) doesn't exist in response**.
But if `print(qs.columns)` the columns *send_datetime, status, etc.* will be printed.

Response:

```
[
    {
        "model": "notifications.newsletter",
        "pk": 42,
        "fields": {
            "start_datetime": "2022-01-21T21:56:09Z",
            "text": "This is test message for 900 operator code.",
            "filter": 1,
            "end_datetime": "2022-01-21T18:00:00Z"
        }
    },
]
```

I need something like:

```
[
    {
        "model": "notifications.newsletter",
        "pk": 43,
        "fields": {
            "start_datetime": "2022-01-21T22:03:26Z",
            "text": "This is test message for 904 operator code.",
            "filter": 2,
            "end_datetime": "2022-01-21T18:00:00Z",
            "messages": [
                {
                    "send_datetime": "2022-01-21T22:03:26Z",
                    "status": 0,
                    "newsletter_id": 43,
                    "client_id": 1
                },
            ]
        }
    },
]
```

**Is it possible to serialize it normally?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use nested model serializers from [Django REST Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer) for your purposes like this:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class MessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = "__all__"

class NewsletterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    messages = MessageSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Newsletter
        fields = "__all__"
```

And use `NewsletterSerializer` in your view:

```
from django.core.serializers import serialize
from django.http import HttpResponse

from .models import Newsletter


def some_view(request):
    sql = 'SELECT nn.*,nm.*FROM notifications_newsletter nn ' \
          'LEFT JOIN notifications_message nm ' \
          'ON nn.id=nm.newsletter_id_id ORDER by nm.status DESC'
    qs = Newsletter.objects.raw(sql)
    qs_json = NewsletterSerializer(qs, many=True).data
    return HttpResponse(qs_json, content_type='application/json')
```

Also you have to do some other changes in your code:

1. You have to rename your fields `newsletter_id`, `client_id` to `newsletter`, `client` respectively. You can read more about it [here](https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/foreign-key-with-id-suffix.html).
2. You have to specify [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) in your `newsletter` foreign key in the `Message` model. Set it to `messages` like this:

```
newsletter = models.ForeignKey('Newsletter', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='messages')
```

3. You have to rename your `filter` field because it is the reserved keyword.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It begins to work at least. But `qs_json = NewsletterSerializer(qs, many=True).data` return `Return List` object. Is there any possibility to return json?

Comment: You can try `json.dumps(NewsletterSerializer(qs, many=True).data)` if you need `JSON` object instead of `list`.

Comment: `json.dumps` will return a json string. To get the appropriate object, use `json.loads(json.dumps(NewsletterSerializer(qs, many=True).data))` instead